# debugging remains same after making changes in my original program

Tags: c#

**my program was going correctly but after few weeks**

debug remains the same as i debug and after making changes in program nothing is changing after debug.
please help.

here is my code

```
namespace Payroll
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=sample; Integrated Security=true");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        /*cs.Open();//testing for checking connection
            MessageBox.Show(cs.State.ToString());
            cs.Close();*/
        BindingSource tblenameBS = new BindingSource();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void CompanyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Company_Main_Interface().Show();
        this.Hide();

    }

    private void exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();

    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void employeesbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employee_main_interface e1 = new employee_main_interface();
        e1.Show();
    }


    private void employees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }





}
```

}

Comment: Maybe cleaning solution or delete bin folder might help. also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2417042/1129995

Comment: What are you asking?  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: So you're saying you update your code, but when you debug it in Visual Studio, the application doesn't reflect those updates?

Comment: What change did you make?  There's not a whole lot going on in there.

Comment: I always get an unclosed feeling when someone asks a question but doesn't reply to comments or provide more information

Comment: jonesy: exactly the same problem u highlighted

Comment: hey everybody thanks after clicking the rebuilding solution button my problem resolved