# Can't Debug WPF project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I have VS 2015 Community using C#. I created a WPF application.

When I hit F5 or play Visual Studio starts to debug the application as normal. I even see the Diagnostics showing Memory Usage and CPU (but it locks up, for example at 20 ms and stays there). The problem is that sometimes the application will open and run when debugging, most the time it does not. Important to note that visual studio itself isn't locking up, just the diagnostic tool window.

If I run without debugging the application opens as normal and there are no problems, but if I want debugging the application doesn't even open.

I am sorry I have no errors to show because I get no errors or warnings. It simply just wont open during debugging.

Is there a patch/update I missed or has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Please file a bug on VS Feedback with all the details and screenshots you can provide : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. If I don't get a solution here I will post this on there. Thank you =)

Comment: I had what sounds like the same problem. I disabled `Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging` in tools, options, Debugging. Some kind of conflict with Symantec. Not ideal but being able to debug is better than having diagnostics.

Comment: @Crowcoder that fixed it =) thanks! if you add this as an answer ill upvote it. again, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had what sounds like the same problem. I disabled `Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging` in Tools → Options → Debugging. In my case it was some kind of conflict with Symantec (per the event log). Not ideal but being able to debug is better than having diagnostics.

> UPDATE

I looked up the help desk ticket I filed for this incident and it was not the event log, I remembered that incorrectly. What was happening was that the `edpa.exe` process (a Symantec process which is controlled by group policy at my office) was thrashing the processor whenever I would debug. The fix/workaround is the same. I have since got a new PC and I do not experience the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting Visual Studio / PC or re-building the solution?

It may help.

Comment: Yes. Even if that did fix it, I need to restart my IDE each time I need to debug?

Comment: Not ideal, there are many possible reasons why the debugger is not working, check this link, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417036/why-the-debugger-doesnt-work

Comment: Sorry, but that is a different issue. Breakpoints not getting hit while the application is actually running when debugging means that person got past the point I did. If you read the OP, "I was able to debug it, suddenly the debugger is never hit." I was not able to debug period. When breakpoints don't get hit the IDE will even discolor the breakpoint warning you that your source is out of sync. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

There should be no conflict with Symantec NIS (current version 22.6.0.142).  It (your question submittal plus the accepted answer) sounds more like an available memory issue; my NIS reports high memory usage when I start up VS, so I sometimes (not always) have Diagnostics failing to start up, but debugging always would continue. Perhaps adding more physical memory is the solution for you; but for now, turning off `Enable Diagnostic Tools While Debugging` is just a bandaid.

Comment: Well, I would have to disagree. This happens with a brand new WPF project. Where I can fully debug a nopCommerce source code solution that has extra plugin projects included (Currently has 58 projects in the solution). This HUGE solution debugs perfectly fine along with the diagnostic window not locking up with no memory issues. I shouldn't be having this problem with a fresh WPF project. I really really doubt its a memory issue.

Comment: I don't want to push the issue at all, but it sounds all the more reason to suspect reaching the memory limit.

Comment: Did you read what I said at all? Were not pushing the issue, but explain how a 58 project solution does not run into this problem where a 1 project solution does with no code because of memory issues? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelD.O'Connor, see my updated answer. I agree with MrKeeame, it is not memory. This happened with any project, new or existing. Web, winform, console, etc. The cpu usage on edpa.exe spiked and a reinstall (by help desk) of whatever symantec system we are using did not resolve it.