# Debugging stop working in EWS functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2017, exchangewebservices

I am debugging some issue, and it gives me this exception and then no other call works to this through Stream Notification

[image: Debug Error Ouptput]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that what do you mean with "Debugging stop"? Is that visual studio doesn't stop on the breakPoint? If so, you can try to rebuild your project and delete bin folder. Please refer to this link:

[Why the debugger doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417036/why-the-debugger-doesnt-work)

Also, I saw the issue about ServiceRequestException which represents an error that occurs when a service operation request fails. I don't know what servcie of EWS you're using. Maybe you can try to use a simple code to test your VS and see if this problem will happen again. However, you need to make sure which lines or codes occurs the issue.